# Get notification when AWS Device Farm finished a run

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codepipeline, aws-device-farm, amazon-cloudtrail

How can I get notified when a Device Farm run is finished ?
Is it possible to get the report into s3 bucket ? So it can be use as a source  trigger in CodePipeline ?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get notified when a Device Farm run is finished?

One way to do that would be to have a small program with continuously calls get-run and checks the status. There are no waiters in boto3(assuming you're using this) for Device Farm at the time of writing this
https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore/data/devicefarm/2015-06-23

> Is it possible to get the report into s3 bucket ?

Device Farm's artifacts are already in s3 however it's in the Device Farm account and not in the account the run was scheduled with. We can see they're in s3 already from the create-upload command which returns a s3 presigned URL.

> So it can be use as a source trigger in CodePipeline ?

That would be cool but this would be something the service doesn't do on our behalf at the moment. You would need to write the script to check if the run is finished, pull the artifacts, then reupload the artifacts to another s3 bucket.

Here's the links to those APIs needed in boto3

- [get_run](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/devicefarm.html#DeviceFarm.Client.get_run)
- [list_artifacts](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/devicefarm.html#DeviceFarm.Client.list_artifacts)
- [upload files example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html)